# Php: get results sets from database via mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am encountering a problem while extracting info from a database using php+mysql and thought it will be good if somebody here may suggest a way out.

**Problematic Code:**

```
$selectedProtocols=array(1,2);
for($i = 0; $i<2; $i++)
{
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT throughput FROM session where mainProtocol='$selectedProtocols[$i]'");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
      $throughput_temp += $row['throughput'];
    }
  $selectedProtocols[$selectedProtocols[$i]]=$throughput_temp;
}
```

Following are the concerned database enteries:

```
mainProtocol  name  throughput
1             Skype 34
2             HTTP  43
1             FTP   54
```

Now, following LOC gives correct output i.e. (34+54=) 88

```
echo "1 has throughput=".$selectedProtocols[$selectedProtocols[0]]."<br>";
```

But, following LOC gives ouput as zero instead of 43

```
echo "2 has throughput=".$selectedProtocols[$selectedProtocols[1]]."<br>";
```

I think there is some problem with method of fetching the result set while querying database. Any idea what wrong am I doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're bug aside (although this should fix it too), *you would be better off only doing one query*. I would rewrite this as:

```
$selectedProtocols = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `throughput`, `mainProtocol` FROM `session` WHERE `mainProtocol` IN (1,2)");

while( $row = mysql_fetch_object($result) ) {
  if ( !isset($selectedProtocols[$row-> mainProtocol]) ) {
    $selectedProtocols[$row->mainProtocol] = $row->throughput;
  } else {
    $selectedProtocols[$row->mainProtocol] += $row->throughput;
  }
}
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine...
The only thing I see is have you initialized the $throughput_temp variable earlier?
You might want to put it before the while and after the $result.
That way your variables won't get reused from the last run.
Try debugging the loop by adding an echo for the while, counting the amount of times it runs while the $i is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `throughput_temp` being initialized? It should be initialized to 0 at the beginning of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm *very* confused by your use of the `$selectedProtocols` array there.

Consider this line:

```
// sp = selectedProtocols ... too much typing otherwise!

$sp[$sp[1]]

// given that $sp == [1, 2]
// resolve the inner

$sp[1] == 2 // therefore:
$sp[$sp[1]] == $sp[2]

// but there is no $sp[2], hence the error
```

I would change it to this:

```
$sp = array(1 => 0, 2 => 0);

foreach (array_keys($sp) as $id) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT throughput FROM session where mainProtocol = '$id'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   
        $sp[$id] += $row['throughput'];
    }
}
```

---

**Response to comment:**

> when the array sp is (1=>0,2=>34,6=>67,15=>56...)

To loop through an array which doesn't have sequential (or even numeric) keys, you can use a couple of methods, but the easiest one is `foreach`. There are two forms of the `foreach` loop:

```
$array = array(1=>0, 2=>34, 6=>67, 15=>56);

// the first form:
foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo $value;    // "0", "34", "67", "56"
}

// the second form:
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . "," . $value;    // 1,0 2,34 6,67 15,56
}
```

So you see that you could use the second method there to get all the ids and values from the array.

Comment: This solves the problem a little bit but now i need to access the values only if i know the keys like to print the values i must type

echo "Value:". $sp[1];
echo "Value:". $sp[2];

but the problem is that i actually do not have only 2 items in the array: sp, rather i have 30 to 40 ids in it and i therefore don't want to write 30 to 40 lines to print the values. Can i do it with the help of a loop? such that i get output as:

Value  of 1 is 0
Value of 2 is 34
Value of 6 is 67
Value of 15 is 56
.
.
.
when the array sp is (1=>0,2=>34,6=>67,15=>56...)

Answer (score 0):

`$throughput_temp` is not re-initialized at the top of the for loop. Besides that, your code would be clearer without the unnecessary array nesting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but I think I see a logic error in your code.

```
$selectedProtocols=array(1,2);
for($i = 0; $i<2; $i++)
{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT throughput FROM session where mainProtocol='$selectedProtocols[$i]'");
  $throughput_temp=0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
      $throughput_temp += $row['throughput'];
    }
  $selectedProtocols[$selectedProtocols[$i]]=$throughput_temp; 
/* $selectedProtocols[$selectedProtocols[$i]] is equivalent to $selectedProtocol[1 or 2]. 
Therefore you are escaping the index 0 of your array and automatically starts at 1, in your
 case. So the next iteration gives you index 2 which is already out of bounds for your 
array.*/
    }
```

Try this code:

```
 $selectedProtocols=array(1,2);
for($i = 0; $i<2; $i++)
{
  $throughput_temp = 0;
 // echo $selectedProtocols[$i];
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT throughput FROM session where mainProtocol='$selectedProtocols[$i]'");
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {   
      //echo $row['throughput'];
      $throughput_temp += $row['throughput'];
    }
  $selectedProtocols[$i]=$throughput_temp;
}
echo "1 has throughput=".$selectedProtocols[0]."<br>";
echo "2 has throughput=".$selectedProtocols[1]."<br>";
```